# How can I extract all required data to re-encrypt browser-decrypted requests identically?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

I want to be able to reencrypt the web responses that Chrome or Firefox receive from a HTTPS server, in a way that they are identical to the original sent by the server.
Is this possible? What would I need to be able to do it?

EDIT: To clarify, I think the first thing that would be required is the client's public key. But given that modern TLS uses forward-secrecy and keys are exchanged in a somewhat complex process, is there anything else required?

Comment: the private key of the server ...

Comment: Isn't the server using the public key of the client instead? I think what you are describing is for authentication. Otherwise anyone with the public key of the server would be ablt to decrypt it. What I want is to encrypt again in an identical way.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The session is encrypted by using symmetric session key which is negotiated during SSL handshake. If you can obtain session key, you will be able to reencrypt HTTPS messages.

Comment: Is that session key generally available within a browser API? And, is that all that is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate only the encrypted messages than you would need the symmetric keys used for encryption and also the random initialization vectors used together with these keys. Additionally you would need to know how much data got encrypted in each SSL record so you could replicate it exactly.

If you also want to replicate the SSL handshake you would also need to know the client and server random values used in the handshake, the servers certificate including its private key and if client certificates are used the same for the clients certificate. Additionally you would need to know which extensions got used and in which order, the ciphers offered by the client (and their order), protocol versions used etc. If DH or ECDH key exchange is done it gets even more complex.

And I'm pretty sure that I've missed something you also need. But even to get all of the values I've mentioned is nearly impossible unless you have very deep control of client and server, i.e. deeper than the API of the usual TLS stacks offers.

Comment: All these applies to encrypted messages too or only handshake?

Comment: @alvatar: the first parapgraph is about *"replicate only the encrypted messages"*. The second one about *"also want to replicate the SSL handshake"*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steffen Ullrich for you answer. I'm only interested in messages. And I would have low level access to the stream. Would it be feasible in such case?

Comment: @alvatar: I don't know how low level your access is but while you might get access to the keys using the API and might also get the amount of date inside a record you usually don't get easy access to the initialization vectors. But of course, if you can modify the TLS library you should get access to all the data needed inside the TLS library to encrypt messages and thus you can replicate the encryption.

Comment: I would only have access to traffic via a proxy, but I'm guessing those initialization vectors are exchanged in an already encrypted connection, right?

Comment: @alvatar: The IV can be extracted from the encrypted message if you have the encryption key. But you would not only keep the IV but also the encryption key to replicate the message. But inside an SSL interception proxy you don't have full control over the encryption key because how key exchange inside the TLS handshake works: its not an exchange were each side shows its key but the key gets derived from combining client and server data.

Comment: thanks a ton for your explanations, they are invaluable to me. In summary, which information would need to be provided then by the client in order to (willingly) allow me to replicate the encrypted messages given that the client also provides me with the unencrypted version of them?

Comment: @alvatar: getting the same key for encryption on one side of the proxy and on the other side to replicate the messages is not only a question on which information you need. You must actually have active control of the TLS handshakes done by both client and server so that they exchange exactly the data which will result into the needed encryption key. Also you might need to have access to the original servers internals to get the right information because I think it is a hard mathematical problem to find the necessary key exchange parameters which will result in a specific encryption key.

Comment: thanks. My purpose is to try to verify that some of the information sent selectively by the client to the proxy has actually been sent by the origin server. My idea was to replicate the encryption and compare with the original response by the origin server.

Comment: @alvatar: Since both client and server of the original connection know the encryption key both can create encrypted messages with this key and you cannot distinguish who of these two created the message.

Comment: but as long as I'm confident that what the client sends me unencrypted is what the server sent encrypted before through the proxy, I'm ok. Is that even achievable?

Comment: @alvatar: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem you are trying to solve and what kind of setup you have. Comments are a bad place to get more details on it, especially since your original question was answered. I recommend that you instead ask a new question where you explain the original problem you are trying to solve in enough detail. This way you also get more input from the community than you would get if we continue to discuss it in the comments.